# How many instances of the CLR are running?

Tags: .net-3.5

There is a simple Hello World Console Application. We compile it and get an assembly (EXE). The EXE is copied into 5 different folders and run from each of the locations. How many instances of the CLR are running when the 5 copied instances are running at the same time?”

Comment: What makes you ask this question ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Number of CLR and GC instances running on a machine?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/943453/number-of-clr-and-gc-instances-running-on-a-machine)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Each physical process gets its own copy of the CLR because each is hosted separately.  Thus if you create 3 instances of your .NET app you will have 3 copies of the CLR running.  Each process will have at least one AppDomain.  Where it gets sort of tricky is with domain-neutral assemblies.  Domain-neutral assemblies, like some of the system assemblies, are actually shared across AppDomains.  This reduces the footprint of the CLR.

check original answer at : http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/clr/thread/238c5f43-1d12-4c80-a987-0b8fdfd6d7e4

Answer (score 1):

It runs 5 different processes each with its own CLR instance.